# Get executionStats.executionTimeMillis from aggregate

Tags: mongodb, performance, pymongo

I am using python3.10 with pymongo I want to get the execution time, I don't want to use time.time or some similar library since I only want the query time

```
pipeline_ref3 = [
     {"$match": {"TP_FAIXA_ETARIA": {"$gte": 1, "$lte": 10}}},
     {"$lookup": {"from": "prova", "localField": "id_prova", "foreignField": "_id", "as": "dados_prova"}},
     {"$project":{"TP_FAIXA_ETARIA": 1,  "dados_prova.TX_RESPOSTAS_LC": 1, "dados_prova.TX_GABARITO_MT": 1 }}
] 

db.aluno.explain("executionStats").aggregate(pipeline_ref3)
```

I've this error:

```
`File /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pymongo/collection.py:3445, in Collection.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3439 if "." not in self.__name:
   3440     raise TypeError("'Collection' object is not callable. If you "
   3441                     "meant to call the '%s' method on a 'Database' "
   3442                     "object it is failing because no such method "
   3443                     "exists." %
   3444                     self.__name)
-> 3445 raise TypeError("'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to "
   3446                 "call the '%s' method on a 'Collection' object it is "
   3447                 "failing because no such method exists." %
   3448                 self.__name.split(".")[-1])

TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'explain' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.`
```

Comment: You might want to use [`pymongoexplain`](https://pypi.org/project/pymongoexplain/).

Comment: @rickhg12hs ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymongoexplain' 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
In  [2]:
Line 1:     from pymongoexplain import ExplainableCollection

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymongoexplain'

Comment: If you want to try/use `pymongoexplain`, you will need to install it.